# Regex and RSS Feed

Tags: java, android, regex

i write a simple Rss Feed reader now i have this problem, in the item description i have the text but this text have this caracters `<br/>`
for example

> "my dog `<br/>` is black and he `<br/>` stay on table "

now i wont to clear the string from this caracters, i wirte this metod

```
private static String IsMatch(String s, String pattern) {
    try {
        Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
        return matcher.group();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
      return "Error";
    } }
```

and

```
String regex ="[<br/>]";

theString2=IsMatch(theString,regex);
 AppLog.logString(theString2);
```

but But this method return always Error. Can any one tell me what's the problem?

best regads 
Antonio

Comment: What don't you simply use replace(CharSequence,CharSequence) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never invoke find() on your matcher. You must invoke find() before invoking group() (and test that find() returns true).

I am not sure of what your method `IsMatch` is supposed to do. As it is, it will either return the match (ie, `"<br/>"`, assuming you invoke `find()` before) either return `"Error"`.

Also, don't put the brackets around `<br/>` in your regexp, they are not needed.

I wouls really consider using replace instead of regexp for your purposes:

```
String s = "my dog <br/> is black and he <br/> stay on table ".replace("<br/>","");
```

As a recommendation, don't catch an exception without logging the it. They provide valuable information that should not be hidden. It make debug really hard when a problem occurs.

Comment: Hi Guillaume thanks for your help, i fixed the problem,`private static String IsMatch(String s, String pattern) {
        try {
            Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
             Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
            
            String tmp = matcher.replaceAll("");       
        return tmp;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            return e.toString();
        }  
}` and i don't put the brackets around <br/> best regads antonio

Comment: @AntonioDeCurtis If you really want to use regexps, you can use string.replaceAll(String, String) which takes a regexp as first argument and a replacement as a second. But I would still recommend the usage of replace(CharSequence, CharSequence) as it is much more efficient and less tricky (you don't have to worry about escaping).

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex ="(\<br\/\>)";
```

I think you need to pay attention to the grammar details about the regular expression:
1. escape the "<" like special characters

different language of regular expression have different specifications